# Is there a tool to convert i18n yaml files to gettext po format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, yaml, gettext, i18n-gem

I'd like to convert rails i18n yaml files to gettext po format. I tried https://github.com/pejuko/i18n-translators-tools but it doesn't worked as expected in my case. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this helps, but it showed up in a quick search:
https://github.com/pejuko/i18n-translators-tools:

> This package brings you useful utility and library which can help you to handle locale files and translations in your Ruby projects. It is build upon i18n library and extends it's simple format so you can simply track field changes or keep translator's notes. Conversion back to simple format is possible and as simple as call 'i18n-translate strip'. Offers also built-in simple console editor.

And from the documentation:

> Simple conversion from one file format to another:
>
> ```
> i18n-translate cze.yml cze.po
> i18n-translate cze.po cze.properties
> ```

Answer (score 0):

See http://github.com/unho/yaml2po for one solution that works for me (after working around one bug, so check its Issues page on github)